# Redirection from files using operator < in C

Tags: c, linux, bash, io-redirection

I wrote a program that simulate the `bash` command in Linux, in C. 
It works perfectly with inputs from the **keyboard**, meaning:

- `application > file`: redirect stdout of app to file(write output to file)
- `application < file`: redirect stdin of app from file (read input from file)
- `application  >> file`: redirect stdout of app to file (append output to file)
- `app1 | app2`: redirect stdout of app1 to stdin of app2
- `app &`: means that app should be executed in the background

All these work, when I enter the command from the keyboard, as mentioned above.

In order to complete my assignment, I need to add one more element, which is 
redirection from a file. Meaning, if my program is called `bashSimulator`, then 
if I do this:

```
bashSimulator < fileWithCommands
```

then my program needs to get all the commands from the `fileWithCommands`  and execute them.

I have no idea how to do the redirection from a file.

Comment: You probably need to be able to run `app < inputfile` from your `bashSimulator` and not `bashSimulator < inputfile`?

Comment: @UlrichDangel: No , I need to take all the commands from `inputfile` and execute them with `bashSimulator` . I really do need to do : `bashSimulator < inputfile` . I need to read all the commands in `inputfile` , each command is separated from the other with `\n` ... I thought about using the `argv` and `argc` of `main`  but that didn't work .

Comment: you don't need to do anything special as the inputfile is provided as stdin. If you are already reading your commands from stdin then everything should already work

Comment: @UlrichDangel: Believe me that if `bashSimulator < inputFile` had worked , I wouldn't be asking you that question.

Comment: It depends on your code how you implement reading the commands. But as i said the input file is provided via STDIN this means you have to read the commands from STDIN. You implemented the `app < inputfile` operation yourself so it should be pretty clear what's happening with `bashSimulator < inputfile`

Comment: @UlrichDangel: Can I send you the complete code so you can take a look ? I would have posted the entire code here ,but a lot of my classmates and TAs are here every now & then ...

Comment: I don't understand what you are missing. Emulating a shell and doing those redirects is much more complicated than reading strings from stdin, which you _are aleadry doing_ if what you state above is true. `bashSimulator` doesn't do the redirection in the command you state; the shell that runs it does.

Comment: No, i won't do your homework, but as i said (and as you already mentioned in your question) `app < inputfile` means **redirect stdin of app from file (read input from file)**. This also means `bashSimulator` will receive the commands via stdin. In other words: If `bashsimulator` will always read the commands from `STDIN` everything should be fine

Comment: @UlrichDangel: The homework is done .Pretty lovely shell , if I may add :) . I didn't ask you to do my HW  . Just asked to take a look and maybe see something that I didn't see and wrote wrong .I'll just post it here .

Comment: @ron maybe a link to a github repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You read the commands from stdin instead of from a batch file or interactively from the user. Use `isatty(3)` to figure out if this is the case.